# Setting up multiple display for window 10

Tags: windows-10, display

I have a 1080p monitor and a 4K TV connected to the same TV. Normally I use the monitor for general use and the TV for movie and gaming. They are positioned in a way that is hard to see the monitor when I am looking at the TV.

So I really prefer to set it to mirrored, since I can fully operate the PC on TV when I am using the TV. But this obviously doesn't work when I am gaming since the monitor and TV have different resolution and only my TV have HDR support. So every time i game on TV, I have to go to display option and change it to "extend these display" and set my TV as primary. This is kinda a pain. Is there easier way?

Ideally, I want to set up both display as "primary". Similar to virtual desktop on window 10. by that I mean, if I load a game or program on TV, it will open in TV only, and vice versa. But I can still drag program across if I need to.

If there is no other way then is it possible to make desktop icons appear on both secondary and primary display

Comment: "If there is no other way then is it possible to make desktop icons appear on both secondary and primary display" - Yes, but you have already determined, that method isn't an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the “Project” sidebar. All configurations (clone, extend, only second) are accessible with keyboard or mouse.

My recommendation is to use “Second screen only” when using your TV to play games or whatever.

Keep in mind that mixed DPI still isn’t *that* great, so you might want to set your TV to 100% scaling. It won’t affect games anyway.

Your envisioned method can unfortunately not be accomplished. Neither “semi-virtual” desktops nor having the icons display on both screens. Well, you could always create a copy of all icons and put them on the second screen.

Comment: Thanks, that kinda works. My keyboard is Corsair K70 so its programable. is there away to set one of the key as "Second screen only" to make life simpler?

Guess what i really wanted can be achieve by setting up each screen as a standalone desktop and there seems to be programs that does that. but i assume there will be a moderate performance impact , so not really a valid way to do it.

Comment: Regular Windows does not support multi-seat operation. I very much doubt games will behave as desired with software like that. // You can create macros (e.g. Win+P, Down, Down, Down, Enter) to further ease switching displays.